# How to do SQL update in Azure cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I played with the same code that uses the @Query annitation e.g.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM c")
List<User> getAllUsers();
```

However, how do I do the equivalent of SQL Update e.g.?

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE c set c.firstName = @documentFirstName")
void updateUsersName(@Param("documentFirstName") String documentFirstName);
```

This example above doesn't work, is there some other syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The Cosmos DB SQL API only supports the Select statement. Partially updating a document isn't [**`supported yet`**](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document).

If you are using the SDK, To update a document you have to use the Upsert-Method:
[**`DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.upsertdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) Method

**UPDATE**:

Partial update feature is supported since November 2021. The feature is [GAed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update).

Comment: Thank you, however I'm using the Java SDK azure-cosmos 4.0.0-preview.1, I'm new to Azure SDK and I'm able to create a Repository with annotations based on the provided example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-cosmos-db however I don't know how to create DocumentClient object